# How to combine data from two reactive streams in project reactor?

Tags: java, spring-boot, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I started using Project Reactor recently and I can't work out how to work with nested streams. I want to update data of outer Mono with some data of inner Mono.

```
 @GetMapping("/search")
    public Mono<Github> combineGithubData() {
        WebClient client = WebClient.create("https://api.github.com");
        Mono<Github> data = client.get().uri(URI.create("https://api.github.com/users/autocorrectoff")).retrieve().bodyToMono(Github.class);
        data = data.map(s -> {
            client.get().uri(URI.create("https://api.github.com/users/Kukilej")).retrieve().bodyToMono(Github.class).map(m -> {
                s.setXXX(m.getName());
                return m;
            });

            return s;
        });
        return data;
    }
```

The field XXX is always returned as null, although I have set it to a value from inner Mono. I'm pretty sure this would work in RxJs. How do I make this work with Project Reactor?

edit:
the code of the Github class

```
import lombok.*;

@Getter @Setter
@Builder
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Github {
    private String login;
    private int id;
    private String node_id;
    private String avatar_url;
    private String gravatar_id;
    private String url;
    private String html_url;
    private String followers_url;
    private String following_url;
    private String gists_url;
    private String starred_url;
    private String subscriptions_url;
    private String organizations_url;
    private String repos_url;
    private String events_url;
    private String received_events_url;
    private String type;
    private boolean site_admin;
    private String name;
    private String company;
    private String blog;
    private String location;
    private String email;
    private String hireable;
    private String bio;
    private int public_repos;
    private int public_gists;
    private int followers;
    private int following;
    private String created_at;
    private String updated_at;
    private String XXX;

}
```

Comment: map() is used to transform a value into another value synchronously. For example, "foo" to "FOO", using string.toUppercase(). If you need to transform a value  asynchronously, by doing an asynchronous call, then you need flatMap().

Answer (score 3):

Your inner stream is not getting subscribed to. Either us `flatMap`, or better yet, use `zip`:

```
data
    .zipWith(client.get().uri(...).retrieve().bodyToMono(Github.class))
    .map(tuple2 -> {
        //update tuple2.getT1() with m.getName() and return the updated tuple
        return tuple2.mapT1(tuple2.getT1().setXXX(tuple2.getT2().getName()));
    })
    .map(tuple2 -> tuple2.getT1() //updated s);
```

`zipWith()` subscribes to the inner stream.

Comment: doesn't compile. mapT1 in Tuple2 cannot be applied to void

Comment: There's a chance it won't compile as I made certain assumptions while writing the map. For instance, I assume that you've used a fluent API for s. Therefore, .setXXX returns an updated object of type s. If you modify it a bit, it'll work. Please consider accepting the answer if it works.

Comment: I have edited the post and pasted the code of the Github class , which is the type of s. You can copy this code, paste it in any spring boot project with webflux added on it's path and see for yourself that this is not compiling

Comment: Add @Accessors(chain=true) and it'll work. Further, I think the answer resolves the basic error that you were facing (your inner stream not getting subscribed to). You can modify the tuple2 as you want.